# Add ObjC project to Swift Project

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am have two existing projects. One I have written in ObjC and the other in Swift following along from online tutorials.

I would like to know how I can import the entire ObjC project into my Swift project.

Can this be easily done?

Comment: You can Use your all obj c class in swift project not entire obj c project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Swift’s compatibility with Objective-C lets you create a project that
>   contains files written in either language. You can use this feature,
>   called mix and match, to write apps that have a mixed-language
>   codebase. Using mix and match, you can implement part of your app’s
>   functionality using the latest Swift features and seamlessly
>   incorporate it back into your existing Objective-C codebase

Checkout [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) reference from Apple of how to import your Objective-C files into your Swift project.

The most important thing is the `bridging header`, checkout the reference above and follow the steps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by easy, is there a one-click solution? No. But you can drag all of your Obj-c stuff into your swift project and use it no problem though. You just need to set up a bridging header. (for storyboards and nibs you may need to reconnect some stuff)

If you are talking about using it as a framework then that is a seperate story.

Answer (score 0):

For this First add bridging Header in your Project

[image]

Then Drag and drop your Obj c file in swift project and import this file in In **YourProject-Bridging-Header.h** ,see

```
#import "ObjectiveCClass.h"
```

After this You can use this class in swift class without doing anything more.